# For all naturals $n: n<x<n+1 \implies x \notin N$

Tags: real-analysis, induction

I've been having trouble proving that there are no natural numbers between two consecutive natural numbers.
 The axioms and definitions I'm using are the same of this question: https:\math.stackexchange.com/questions/2896530/prove-that-if-m-n-are-natural-and-mn-then-m-n-is-natural

My attempt. I tried by induction: ($x$ is a real)

Basis: $0<x<1 \implies x \notin N$

This can be easily proved by noting that the union of $\{0\}$  and $[1, + \infty [ $ is inductive and contains 0 thereore is a superset of naturals and easy to show that $0<x<1 $              implies that $x$ is not in that set therefore $x$ is not natural.

I can't proceed, no idea how to prove that the hypothesis for some $k$ implies for $k+1$ since I can't enumerate all numbers before $k$  like in the basis case.

Note that I haven't yet proved that if $m,n \in N$ and $m>n$ then $m-n \in N$

Comment: it easy to prove by contradiction after you proved the initial case as $0<x-k<1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume the claim holds for $k-1 < x < k$, where $k\geq 1$. Now suppose there is a natural number $k< y <k+1$. Then $0<y-k<1$ must also be a natural number since $y>k$. This contradicts the case $k=1$.

---

Assuming here $0\notin N$.

> $$(\forall m\in N)\left (m\neq 1 \implies m-1\in N\right )\tag{1} $$

**Proof.** Suppose for a contradiction $m-1\notin N$. The set $N\setminus \{m\}$ is inductive. Indeed, $1\in N\setminus \{m\}$ and if $n\in N\setminus \{m\}\subset N$, then $n+1\in N$. In particular $n+1\neq m$, thus $n+1\in N\setminus \{m\}$. But now $N \subseteq N\setminus\{m\}$, a contradiction.

**Proof of claim.** Let $m\in N\setminus \{1\}$. We will show by induction that for all $n<m$ it holds that $m-n\in N$.  The base case is establised by $(1)$. Suppose $m-k\in N$. Then for the case $k+1<m$ we may again note by $(1)$ that 
$$m-(k+1) = (m-k) -1\in N. $$

Comment: I haven't yet proved that if $y$ and $k$ are naturals and $y>k$ then $y-k$ is natural. I asked that in my other question, but the answer of that question assumes the title of this one...

Comment: @HortaBe I added content for the sake of completion.

Comment: you are assuming that the naturals start at 1 and not 0,  right?

Comment: @HortaBe that's right. The result doesn't depend on this. It's just convenient. You may instead prove $1<x<1+1$ is impossible. You arrive at the same conclusions.

Comment: yes, I was just making sure. Although I don't understand very well your proof of $(1)$ I was able to prove it in another way, and prove the same result so thanks you vary much.

Answer (score 0):

These types of problems can be surprisingly hard since it's not clear what can be taken for granted and what can't.

I will give it a go taking the following as given:

- $N = \{0,1,2,\ldots\}$
- if $n \in N$ and $n \not= 0$, then there exists $m \in N$ with $m+1=n$
- the *well-ordering principle*: any nonempty set of natural numbers has a least element
- the usual ordering and arithmetic properties of $N$
- your claim that $0 < x < 1$ implies $x \notin N$.

Define $E = \{x \in N \mid \exists n \in N\ n < x < n+1\}$.The goal is to show that $E$ is empty. Assume to the contrary that $E \not= \emptyset$. Then $E$ has a least element $x$. By definition of the set $E$ there exists $n \in N$ with $n < x < n+1$.

How large can $n$ be? If $n \not = 0$ then there exists $m \in N$ with $n=m+1$. This leads to
$$ m+1 < x < m+2$$
which in turn gives $$m < x-1 < m+1.$$
This is precisely what is meant by membership in $E$, giving you that $x-1 \in E$.

This contradicts the minimal nature of $x \in E$. We made two hypotheses: first that $E$ is nonempty, and second that $n \not = 0$. It follows that the most recent hypothesis fails, so we conclude that $n = 0$ and $0 < x < 1$. This, however contradicts the fifth axiom listed above, so the original hypothesis $E \not= \emptyset$ fails.

Thus $E = \emptyset$ and no such $x$ exists.

Comment: I haven't yet proved the well-ordering either, but I'm guessing it's necessary to prove it first. Thanks anyway